# datatables tabletools -> export only selected rows

Tags: jquery, tabletools

I am using datatables with tabletools on a large table which is filled via ajax request.

When user selects several rows, it shows them as selected in the table.

How can i tell the csv/xls export to ONLY export the selected rows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Stupid me...

Just got it:

```
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If for somebody like me `bSelectedOnly` is not working
(e.g always all rows are copied when only certain selected), before you burn into cry, just check if your run `2.2.3` version of `dataTables.tableTools.js` becuase there was bug corrected in this release: https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/commit/a9afb46cb00417db6d0fd6d7697e5d28830bc959

```
Fix #48: `bSelectedOnly` option was not working in 1.10.
* Fix is to use the new `fnGetSelectedIndexes` which gives the
  information required for `bSelectedOnly` when needed.
```