# Datatable export with selected rows

Tags: datatables, export-to-csv, export-to-pdf

I am using datatables with tabletools on a large table which is filled via ajax request.

When user selects several rows, it shows them as selected in the `table`.

How can i tell the csv/pdf export to ONLY export the selected rows?

Thanks in advance

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svbhatt/abhbs4x8/1057/)

Comment: You could use a sql statement to select the rows you want and insert that into a new table. Then export that table

Comment: I want front end export only. With Datatable.

Comment: You should simplify that jsfiddle so it only shows the code for the problem. Pasting a wall of code makes it tough to answer quickly. Then I can probably help you better :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/svbhatt/abhbs4x8/1057/  . Ohk I simplify it

Comment: Its currently giving error while clicking on PDF button. Uncaught TypeError: table.button is not a function

Comment: I also refereed  this link :-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498489/datatables-tabletools-export-only-selected-rows